# How to connect to VPN Server (Username and password) in android programmaticaly

Tags: android

I want to connect to the VPN Server which have username and password in android programmatically.

Please help me to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: what you have did and what problems are occures

Comment: @BirajZalavadia I tried but doing it first time. I could not find good examples to proceed for this, Please help me if you know these

Answer (score 1):

**Try this may be help you**

```
public String getUrlContent(String urlstring,final String user,final String password) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] rawbyte = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlstring);

        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator(){
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password.toCharArray());
            }});
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.connect();
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            try
            {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                        urlConnection.getInputStream());
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int c;
                while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
                {
                    out.write(c);
                }
                out.flush();

                rawbyte = out.toByteArray();

                urlConnection.disconnect();
                in.close();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return new String(rawbyte);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I have a server ip address and username and password and certificates. Where i used in this above code. Can you show me writing some text where it is connected and then all the network will be secure as vpn do this

Comment: then where i use the server ip address which i want to connect (VPN Server). and yourip means my device ip address?

Answer (score 0):

you can try xinkvpn, here is the github link: https://github.com/xinthink/xinkvpn

Comment: I imported the project but can you guide me to import correctly because there are number of errors when i am doing